# Firebase signInWithEmailLink

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to set a password for the user after signing in with `signInWithEmailLink` method?

I didn't find anything about this case

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does `updatePassword` work? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_password.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes it works with updatePassword, I didn't test very well my bad

Answer (score 1):

firebase's `signInWithEmailLink` function's actual purpose is to provide a passwordless sign-in/up method. so if you set a password for your user after signing in with `signInWithEmailLink`, it loses its purpose

you may be looking to verify the user's email which you can get with [sendEmailVerification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?hl=en&authuser=0#send_a_user_a_verification_email)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to set a password for the user after signing in with signInWithEmailLink method?

If you're looking for a way to change the password right after the user has signed in, that means that you're looking for an [update password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_password) operation.

Comment: Hey Achraf. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?